# In Java, the PermGen space is said to be "scaled 30% larger". Does this mean max is no longer necessary?

Tags: java, permgen, jvm-arguments

I recently had cause to look at the [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html#PerformanceTuning) for the `-XX:MaxPermSize` argument to the JVM.

Its documentation says in part:

> 5.0 and newer: 64 bit VMs are scaled 30% larger

Does this mean that `MaxPermSize` is obsolete for Java 1.5 and later virtual machines?  Or, as I suspect, does this scaling information simply describe what happens *up to* the max?

(Actually, come to think of it, 30% of *what*?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

64-bit JVM tends to use more memory because of bigger pointers. To alleviate this growth the *default* sizes of all memory areas in 64-bit JVM were increased. You can still override the defaults and use any values you want.

Moreover, if you already use `-XX:MaxPermSize`, this change is completely irrelevant to you.

Comment: I see; so the default `MaxPermSize` on a 64-bit JVM is `64M + (0.3 * 64M)`?

Comment: @LairdNelson: that's right, I am looking for a complete table somewhere